# print() does not work in a for loop with progressbar

Tags: loops, jupyter-notebook, printing, progress-bar, jupyter-lab

I am coding and printing some plots inside a double for-loop with progressbar in Jupyter-lab. Plots are printed. However, the print statement is not working anywhere. I use paralelization with numba and OMP.

This is a minimum code that should print any string but it does not work:

```
for number in progressbar(range(0,5)):
    print("Inside loop")
    print(number)
    print(str(number))
```

I tried using a self defined function:

```
def my_print(text): # Printing inside for loops requires a flush the stdout afrter every print
    sys.stdout.write(str(text))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

It did not work.

Comment: "This is a minimum code that should print any string but it does not work" - That isn't close to a minimal reproducible example code. The idea behind an MRE is that what you supply would do what you are posting about if put in a new notebook. If you just put the code you supplied in a new notebook, you can verify for yourself if it is an MRE. Then you know you achieved that. We cannot determine your issue from the limited details. My sense would be you have progressbar or something else swallowing your output or delaying it so it isn't posted until later and that final step doesn't occur.

Comment: <continued> But without more details it is hard to say. Read about what a true minimal, reproducible example is under the sub-heading of Help others reproduce the problem' in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).